# HtmlHelp hhc file doesn't show russian characters

Tags: encoding, freepascal, chm

I use free pascal's chmcmd command to create chm file from hhp. After converting content goes right, but left pane side (tree) doesn't show russian characters. I tried to set charset at hhc file to cp1251. And saved file in windows 1251 encoding. After that it shows tree in russian right in cool reader but not in xChm. In windows it still doesnt work, only weird symbols. Utf-8 doesn't work at all.

Comment: Ok i guess i should try this https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2e17127a-8742-4997-bcfc-b1396aab5443/the-nonunicode-program-setting-must-be-the-same-with-the-language-in-sandcastle?forum=devdocs

Comment: Please test chm validity with the windows helpviewers. The linux alternatives are often buggy. I don't know the encoding status of chmcmd

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft CHM help format is very old and not maintained anymore. It wasn't created with Unicode in mind and various tricks need to be done in order to be able to generate CHM files for certain encodings:

- You Windows is setup in the target language of the help file
- The content HTML pages must be created using the proper charset

Comment: Yes, I had to ask translators to provide context help in the right ANS versions. But you mention that CHM is very old. Microsoft have not exactly provided an alternative yet.